# How to run sql query to return data from different joomla components

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller, joomla, components

I am trying to customize the source files of a Joomla component.

Before the Joomla MVC model introduced, I was able to run SQL queries in a component, Kunena 1.0 to select data from another component. e.g Sobi2.

However, after Kunena 1.5 [MVC model] was introduced, I do not know how / where to add the SQL query to select data from Sobi2.

I believe I need to add some codes in the files of the /models/ or /func/ folder. But can someone provide more detailed assistance on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The data interaction is done by the model, you will find Kunena models in the model folder.

Querying the SOBI2 databse is the same as before, MVC wouldn't actually affect how you do this.

To get your head around MVC, have a look at:

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

For examples of how to query the database in your model, look at:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_database_classes_in_your_script

In simple terms, the Controller directs to the appropriate view (view.html.php), this view then interacts with the model, and then directs to a template file (normally located in the view/tmpl folder.

Hope this helps.